# Laravel get specific column name value with passing column name as string to DB result

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to get the the result of specific column which the name of column is stored in array

I have an array which contain the table name and required column:

```
$table_info = ['table_name' => 'users', 'column_name' => 'email'];
```

and I pass the values to DB class query successfully and it work correctly.

```
$document = DB::table($table_info['table_name'])
            ->select($table_info['column_name'])
            ->where('id', 1)
            ->first();
```

but when I try to get query result according to `$table_info['column_name']` it throws error:

```
return $document->$table_info['column_name'];
```

**Error:**

> Array to string conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put curly brackets around the dynamic property you want to access to:

```php
return $document->{$table_info['column_name']};
```

This way, the whole `$table_info['column_name']` is read entirely and not only `$table_info`, which is an array.